# Angular web component with differential loading gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ɵɵdefineComponent' of undefined

Tags: angular, web-component, ngx-build-plus

My objective is to develop an Angular web component, that I can use in my "normal" parent SPA - *and* a Wordpress site.

When consuming the web component on the Wordpress site, I package everything together in a single bundle with [ngx-build-plus.](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus). This works great.

However, when serving the web component for my parent Angular application, I would like to avoid having Angular part of the bundle (since it's already there). I follow the [blog/guide](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/your-options-for-building-angular-elements/) for differential loading described in the readme - but I'm stuck with this error (root.component is the name of my web component).

```js
root.component.ts:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ɵɵdefineComponent' of undefined
    at root.component.ts:10
    at Module../src/app/root.component.ts (root.component.ts:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

I get the above error when serving with:

```
ng s --extra-webpack-config projects/<name-of-project>/webpack.externals.js --output-hashing=none --project eddy-library --single-bundle
```

As described it works fine with (but it creates big bundle - containing angular).

```
ng s --project <name-of-project> --single-bundle
```

Any help is very welcome. I tried copying everything from the sample repos, but to no help

Comment: Have you found a resolution to this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Nope - currently just fixed the issue with building the large bundle. But this, combined with other things, pushed our team to using svelte instead.